# WordPress Crashing, nginx and fastcgi issue?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, crash, timeout, fastcgi

I currently have this problem with my wordpress website where it will work for about a day after a server restart, but then hit this set of errors:

```
2015/12/15 22:06:42 [crit] 12650#0: *28 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.166.139.20, server: example.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", $
2015/12/15 22:08:19 [error] 3216#0: *18 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/option.php on line 30
PHP message: PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/wp-includes/option.php on line 30" while reading response header from upstream, client: 104.33.64.70, server: example.com, request: "P$
2015/12/15 22:40:08 [error] 3216#0: *197 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.76.15.142, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/$
2015/12/15 22:40:20 [error] 3216#0: *199 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.76.15.19, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/v$
2015/12/15 23:08:27 [error] 3216#0: *201 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.76.15.143, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/$
2015/12/15 23:08:39 [error] 3216#0: *203 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 180.76.15.12, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/v$
2015/12/15 23:20:20 [error] 3216#0: *205 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 104.33.64.70, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/upgrade.php?step=1&backto=%2Fwp$
2015/12/15 23:22:20 [error] 3216#0: *205 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 104.33.64.70, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcg$
2015/12/15 23:57:09 [error] 3216#0: *367 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.166.139.20, server: example.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HT$
2015/12/15 23:57:39 [error] 3216#0: *369 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.166.139.20, server: example.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HT$
2015/12/15 23:57:41 [error] 3216#0: *371 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.166.139.20, server: example.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HT$
2015/12/15 23:57:56 [error] 3216#0: *373 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.166.139.20, server: example.com, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HT$
```

Afterwards, the error log just repeats that (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) code over and over. At this point trying to access the website itself just gives an nginx "an error has occurred" page, telling me to check error logs.

I don't know what exactly is causing the initial holdup, and it looks like after a few time outs the server just locks up entirely. Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Did you contact server technical team?

Answer (score 0):

Someone from 46.166.139.20 tries to guess your password. If you don't use WP's XML-RPC you should disable it.